# Django showing data from previous days

Tags: python, django, postgresql

My code is pretty simple, it queries the database to get a list of future events.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)

def index(request, listing='upcoming'):

    country_name = get_client_ip(request)

    if Location.objects.filter(country=country_name).count() == 0:
        global_scope = True
    else:
        global_scope = False

    if listing == 'upcoming':
        if global_scope == True:
            events = Event.objects.filter(date__gte=now, published=True)
        else:
            events = Event.objects.filter(date__gte=now, published=True, location__country=country_name)        

    elif listing == 'new':
        if global_scope == True:
            events = Event.objects.filter(published=True).order_by('-added')
        else:
            events = Event.objects.filter(published=True, location__country=country_name).order_by('-added')        

    elif listing == 'free':
        if global_scope:
            events = Event.objects.filter(date__gte=now, published=True, price__isnull=True)
        else:
            events = Event.objects.filter(date__gte=now, published=True, price__isnull=True, location__country=country_name)        

    elif listing == 'wishlist':
        events = Event.objects.filter(users = request.user.id, published=True)
    else:
        events = Event.objects.filter(date__gte=now, published=True)

    paginator = Paginator(events, 10)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        events = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        events = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        events = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'events/index.html', { "events": events, 'listing': listing, 'country_name': country_name, })
```

The problem here is that for some reason the site keeps showing events starting in monday, until I update the database with a few events on Friday.

The site runs on postgres and is using django 1.6. I checked and it seemed that setting 
default_transaction_isolation: 'read committed' would solve it. But reading the documentation for postgres I found out it is the default.

Any idea on how I could track what is causing this?

Comment: Where exactly is this code? Is it in a function, or where?

Comment: @DanielRoseman it is inside the views.py file.

Comment: That didn't answer the question. *Where* inside the views file. In a function? At global level? In a class declaration?

Comment: @DanielRoseman sorry. I have updated the question to reflect the full definition of the index page. I believed that in this situation django queried the db everytime a new page was loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for some reason your definition of `now` is outside the function, at module level. That means it is only executed whenever the process starts, and the same value will be used for all requests in that process. Your web server manages its processes, and they can last for days or weeks before being recycled.

Just move that line into the function itself, and it will get a new value every time the function is called.

(Defining values outside a function is a perfectly good technique if you want to define data that *should* be static across requests, however that is not the case here.)